# Website IE To open Excel on a certain worksheet

Tags: javascript, html, vba, excel

Can anyone suggest a way to open an Excel file on a specific worksheet. I had added a href to prompt to download the file but then it'll open on any worksheet.

I have 25 worksheets in 1 excel macro template file and I need to have links on a website which opens to a specific worksheet and hids all the other pages.

Is this possible?

I have tried:

```
<a href="ExcelFileName.xltm#worksheetname!A1>
```

But this doesn't work, can i use javascript (vbs on a broswer has security issues). Is there any other method apart from creating 25 seperaete excel documents?

Comment: I think you have to create 25 different documents.

Comment: Excel will only open to the last sheet that was open when the file was saved. You can technically create a VBA enabled workbook and pass a parameter to the command line when you open it.  Doing this with an HREF is very unlikely to have a good solution though.

Comment: The workbook is VBA - is the command line option viable as in what parameter and how could you do that through HREF?

Comment: I don't think you can do that via an HREF unless your HREF is the full path to an executable `excel.exe workbook.xlsm [params]`.  It is possible to read parameters when an Excel workbook opens (with additional code).

Comment: I have an implementation of the command line option and it works, but I don't have a web server installed in order to figure out how to pass the href parameter (#worksheetname!A) to to the command line. I'd also need to know what browser you are using and how the file is opened from the link (in the browser itself, or downloaded first). Let me know if you want the command line part